# Directory navigating to CSS Stylesheet

Tags: html, css, node.js, ejs

I'm trying to navigate to a stylesheet and I've tried many options but none are working.

```
(/stylesheets/main.css)
(../stylesheets/main.css)
(./stylesheets/main.css)
```

My file tree looks as thus:

```
V1(root)
---- >public
-------- >img
------------ logo.png
-------- >stylesheets
------------ main.css
---- >views
-------- >partials
------------ header.ejs
------------ footer.ejs
-------- landing.ejs
```

I am including my `header.ejs` to `landing.ejs`

Here is the code I'm using:

**header.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Event Ticketing</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/main.css">
</head>
```

**landing.ejs**

```
<% include ./partials/header %>

<h1>Landing Page</h1>
```

When I try to render the landing view I'm not getting any styles linking through at all. I think the path is incorrect but have no idea how to link it.

Comment: I think you need to go up a few directories so by the looks of it you need to do: `../../stylesheets/main.css`. That should take you up to directories to `public`, then into `stylesheets`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you set static path for `public` directory in main node app.

**server.js**

```
// after setting ejs as engine
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
// before routing
```

Answer (score 0):

A "/" used in href references to your domain's root (www.domain.de/) - if your project was in a sub-folder, you would have to include that folder into your link.

The path to your stylesheet is "/public/stylesheets/main.css", unless the folder "V1" (root) is an actual subfolder in your domain - in that case, you would have to prepend "/V1" to the link.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go up one more directory so, by the looks of it, your code should be like this:

`link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../folder/file.css"`

(remember the <> at the start and end)

That should take you up your top level folders, then into stylesheets.